# What is the opposite of a metaphorical barrier?

Tags: metaphors, simile

I am trying to find a noun that describes a person that enables others to be more productive. The opposite of that is a roadblock or barrier.

My first thought was a sail, since the addition of another sail in the correct place allows a ship to reach its destination faster. But this strikes as too obscure.

Is there a shared metaphor/simile that would capture this idea and satisfies these conditions

- noun that can be applied to a person (Bill is a ... )
- not obscure
- helps others achieve their goals better (rather than his own goals)

Comment: Though still obscure a *Jib* is the last sail you add to the smaller sail boats. I'm not the expert but I think it makes a great difference if the others are completely full. Might not be bad to say "Bill is our Jib."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### More literal

As opposed to a hindrance:

- Bill is a [**facilitator**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facilitator):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : someone or something that facilitates something
> *especially* : someone who helps to bring about an outcome (such as learning, productivity, or communication) by providing indirect or unobtrusive assistance, guidance, or supervision
> // the workshop's *facilitator* kept discussion flowing smoothly

---

### More metaphorical

As opposed to a roadblock:

- Bill is a [**passageway**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passageway):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : a way that allows [passage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passage)

Depending on the required nuance, [*gateway*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gateway) could also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head,I can think of these three:

"leg up", "driving force", and "actuator"

Comment: I like "leg up," but it is not a noun. Driving force suggests that the direction comes from a the person I want to describe, rather from the person being helped. Actuator is too obscure.

Comment: Check Merriam-Webster for "leg up". It's a noun.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. But can I say Stockfish is a leg up?

Comment: I couldn't follow what you had to say about "driving force". Looks good to me.

Comment: Someone provides "leg up", I suppose. Perhaps then, try "Impetus".

Comment: Driving force is used to describe a person or thing that causes or controls something. What I have in mind means that the recipient of the help is in control.

Comment: Supporter, assistant, helper. An organization often has staff assistants such as statisticians or librarians or data entry experts. Unfortunately *enabler* is used to describe people who enable bad habits, e.g., drug use. Or are you thinking about something like muse?